# Pass key which name contains blank to redis using bash failed

Tags: bash, double-quotes, single-quotes

For example, i have a key list in file named keys, and some key name contains blank:

```
keya
keyb
"a blank key"
```

I want to get values from redis in bash, so my command is:

```
while read key ;do redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 get $key;done < keys
```

But when the name contains blank, the comand executes failed:

```
none
none
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'type' command
```

Does anynoe knows how to fix this?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Test for an empty variable, `while ...;  do [[ -z "$key" ]] && continue ; redis ...; done`

Comment: or instead of `< keys` use  `< <(grep -v '^$' keys)`

Comment: Having quotes inside the key variable doesn't substitute for not using them around `$key`, because the quotes from your data file are _literal_, quotes inside your source code are _syntax_, and the two don't substitute for each other. Take them out of `"a blank key"` -- the line should be just `a blank key` -- and then make it `get "$key"`, not `get $key`.

Comment: BTW, you'd have the same problem for _any_ key with spaces in it, not just ones where those spaces surround the word "blank". (Empty keys are also a problem when you don't use syntactic quotes at expansion time, because they don't turn into any arguments at all).

Comment: Thanks all of you. @Charles Duffy's way works.